# Missing Menu in Visual Studio (Tools > SQL Server > New Data/Schema Comparison)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

In a video I noticed a menu option in visual studio which I don't have (Tools > SQL Server > Neu Data/Schema Comparison.

[image]

however, when trying to compare the schema in my database I don't have the SQL Server Option.

Where can this option be enabled?

[image]

Comment: When you installed Visual Studio did you include the [Data storage and processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-professional?view=vs-2022#data-storage-and-processing) workload?

Comment: thank you for your reply. this solved the issue.